# Is there a more readable way to express javascript closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

I would like to update some data with JSON when the user clicks on an object. What I came up with is the following double closure.

```
var buildGetJSON = function(m,t,p,u) { 
  return function ()  {
    var buildUpdateParticipants = function(m,t,p) {
      return function(data) { updateParticipants(m,t,data,p); };
    };
    $.getJSON(u, buildUpdateParticipants(m,t,p));
  };
};
marker.on("click", buildGetJSON(marker, title, popmsg, url));
```

It works, but made me wonder if there is a more concise way to put this than writing a closure variable for the two function calls. Any hints?

Comment: Half of those closures seems to be pointless (in that they are only called once and the calls could be constant-folded away). Does this snippet happen to be in a loop?

Comment: @delnan: Yes, there are several markers, it's a loop. Sorry, I wrongly stipped that part away.

Comment: @Mangrangs: I was hoping Haskell. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the second closure is redundant.

```
function buildGetJSON(m,t,p,u) {
  return function() {
    $.getJSON(u, function(data) {
      updateParticipants(m,t,data,p);
    });
  };
}
marker.on("click", buildGetJSON(marker,title,popmsg,url));
```

If you're only using buildGetJSON once, you can further simplify it by making buildGetJSON anonymous.

```
marker.on("click", function(m,t,p,u) {return function() {
  $.getJSON(u, function(data) {
    updateParticipants(m,t,data,p);
  });
};}(marker,title,popmsg,url));
```

Here's another way to do it entirely with anonymous functions. It doesn't collapse into as few lines, but I think it looks a little clearer.

```
!function(m,t,p,u) {
  marker.on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON(u, function(data) {
      updateParticipants(m,t,data,p);
    });
  });
}(marker,title,popmsg,url);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, we just cross-posted I've already added a note about when the added closure is needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Comment deleted (because it isn't part of my answer).

Comment: Redundant, indeed. Thanks a lot. I think I managed to wrap my brain around them a correct number of times now.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply do this?

```
marker.on("click", function () {
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        updateParticipants(marker, title, data, popmsg);
    });
});
```

Looks much more synoptical - at least to me :-)

But be aware: if the variables `marker`, `title` etc. can change, and you don't want that, then you need an additional closure. E.g. if you call this for example in loop, and the variable `marker` (or other variables) changes over the loop! Then you need to enclose your code in another closure within the loop:

```
for (marker in markers) {
    (function (marker) {
        // above code
    })(marker);
}
```

Closures are very nice and very strong feature of JavaScript, once you know how to use them. Look at the "The JavaScript Programming Language" videos from Douglas Crockford, they explain it in a great way.